# Android: Need help to create camera activity screen quickly

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

I am trying to optimize my Camera Loading time. My current design call an activity `"CameraLoading"` when camera icon is clicked. CameraLoading activity starts a new activity `"CameraActivity"` which is the real camera.

To optimize this software, I want to skip CameraLoading activity and directly start CameraActivity. In CameraActivity, my screen (setcontentview layout) is created in the begining of the onCreate but is it not displayed till the time preview is ready.

Due to this issue, when user clicks camera icon , for a long time there is no activity on screen , suddenly Camera opens. Is it true that screen will not comeup till onCreate and onResume functions are completed ?

I need your help in showing some notification or animation on screen which informs user that camera is being opened. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to use a second thread to load the camera. So create your CameraActivity with a simple loading anim and set a thread to load the camera. Once it is loaded you can then set it dynamically into your view and remove the loading icon.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

This link shows using threading to download an image so it doesn't slow down the UI. If you can understand that then you can modify its premise to your purpose. Hope this helps

Some sample code that might give you the idea. This is just psuedo code so take it with a pinch of salt:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...load view as usual

    new LoadCameraTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class LoadCameraTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected CameraClass doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ...perform loading of camera and return the camera object
        return Camera;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(CameraClass result) {
        contentView.add(result);
        contentView.remove(loadingIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wao, that was fast ! Thanks a lot Michael ! Let me try to implement this.

Comment: Your welcome. Welcome to the site and don't forget to up-vote and accept this answer if it works for you.